# Javascript-Why is the last string character not replaced with the given method (in the description)?

Tags: javascript

Why are the two following lines not replacing the last comma with a period, but instead is choosing a different position. I used the refused.textContent[refused.textContent.length -1] to choose the last string character but it's obviously not choosing the last character. What's the problem?

```
refused.textContent = refused.textContent.replace(refused.textContent[refused.textContent.length -1],".");
    admitted.textContent = admitted.textContent.replace(admitted.textContent[refused.textContent.length -1],".");
```

output:

Admit:.Chris, Anne, Colin, Terri, Sam, Kay, Bruce,

Refuse:.Phil, Lola,

Full code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="output" style="height: 100px;overflow: auto;">
      <p class="admitted">Admit: </p>
      <p class="refused">Refuse: </p>
    </div>
    <script>
    var people = ['Chris', 'Anne', 'Colin', 'Terri', 'Phil', 'Lola', 'Sam', 'Kay', 'Bruce'];

    var admitted = document.querySelector('.admitted');
    var refused = document.querySelector('.refused');

    admitted.textContent = 'Admit: ';
    refused.textContent = 'Refuse: '
    var i = 0;

    do {
      if(people[i] === 'Phil' || people[i] === 'Lola') {
        refused.textContent += people[i] + ', ';
      } else {
        admitted.textContent += people[i] + ', ';
      }
      i++;
    } while(i < people.length);

    refused.textContent = refused.textContent.replace(refused.textContent[refused.textContent.length -1],".");
    admitted.textContent = admitted.textContent.replace(admitted.textContent[refused.textContent.length -1],".");

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `.replace(<what should be replaced>, <replacement>)` replaces the **first occurrence** (unless you're using a regular expression with a set `global` flag) of `<what should be replaced>` with `<replacement>`

Comment: thx! makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit monkey patching. Why don't you filter the array into two arrays like this:

```
const accept = ["Phil","Lola"];
const admit = [], refuse = [];
for(const person of people)
  (accept.includes(person) ? admit : refuse).push( person);
```

So to get a comma seperated list we simply join and add a dot at the end:

```
admitted.textContent = admit.join(",") + ".";
refused.textContent = refuse.join(",") + ".";
```